# Named promise results with q.all in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I'm kinda new to this `q` stuff and I find it pretty awesome, but there's something I still can't figure out.

I managed to run some combined promises with `q.all` by passing `q.all` an array of promises. Something like this..

```
var promises = [promiseOne(), promiseTwo()];
q.all(promises).then(function (results) {
    res.send(results);
} );
```

The thing with this is that I would actually want those promises to be named, so I don't have to rely in the order of the promises.

I read somewhere that you can actually pass an object to `q.all`, to have the results named. So that would be something like this:

```
var promises = { promiseOne: promiseOne(), promiseTwo: promiseTwo() }
q.all(promises).then(function(results){
    res.send(results);
});
```

But I guess this just doesn't work the same way as sending an array as I'm not getting the results of my promises in there. The result I get is similar to this one:

```
{
    promiseOne: {
        source: {}
    },
    promiseTwo: {
        source: {}
    }
}
```

So how would you go about getting named results from q.all?

One thing to note is that the amount of promises I will have in the `promises` array is not fixed as I get that from a `GET` param sent by the user to my function.

Also, inside each of my promises I have another array (or object) of promises to be resolved and whose results I would like to be named as well.

Comment: I don't think you can pass an object as an input to `Q.all` and the result of `Q.all` will be an array always

Comment: @thefourtheye Here's where I found that http://blog.500tech.com/really-you-can-do-that-with-promises/ In case #2 he seems to be doing that (not saying it is a trustful resource). Furthermore in the Angular docs for q it states that promises can be an object https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q . Not sure if AngularJS's q is the same as Node's though.

Comment: The [Q.js documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) gives no indication that `Q.all()` will accept an object in place of an array. As a workaround I would suggest that you find a way to include the required name as part of the value with which each promise is resolved.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yep, that's where I'm at now. I return an object with the name of the key in the promise resolution. And then I turn the array that q.all returns to an object too. But I was hoping Q to have a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Another approach that *can* work (scenario permitting) is to exploit the congruity of *three* arrays: 

(1) a Data Array,
(2) the Promises Array which arises from mapping the data array,
(3) the Results Array delivered by `Q.all()`.

If that scenario exists, then when looping through the Results Array (and with the Data Array in scope and still intact), each original data item and its result are associated by array index.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 that's what I was doing in the beginning. But I found the other approach (the one in your previous comment) more elegant. I also found `spread` to be useful for this (instead of `q.all`). But was still hoping to find something else.

Comment: Don't use an ancient library - use bluebird which features a `Promise.props` function that just does this - it's also much faster and has better debug messages. Fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to write the code Roamer wrote with the functionality you asked for (return an object):

```
Q.props = obj => {
    const ps = Q.all(Object.keys(obj).map(x => Q.all([x, obj[x]])));
    return ps.then(x => x.reduce((p, c) => {p[c[0]] = c[1]; return p } , {}));
};
```

Which would let you do:

```
Q.props(promises).then(o => {
    o.promiseOne
});
```

Although you should consider using bluebird if you want all these helper functions.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about bluebird! Any downsides of using bluebird vs q?

Comment: @lascort it's a newer library - so there's that. Q has a more readable source. That's about it.

Comment: Perfect! Just got it working with bluebird! Thank you for the awesomeness. I don't think accepting this answer is good since it doesn't actually suggest bluebird. But if you post an answer doing so the green stuff is yours.

Comment: @lascort I assume you don't know my involvement with bluebird and Q - but I added the line to entertain you :)

Comment: I can't think of a single reason not to use bluebird.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @emory I love how people are convincing me to use bluebird as if I'm not a core contributor to the library :D

Comment: This is the reason why I come here; to remind myself that I'm just an old hack and the future is safe in the hands of the next generation.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I had my doubts about bluebird. No idea what you're on about Q though. The offer stands though, after all I solved it with your comment!

Comment: Didn't see your edit. There you go! Good job on bluebird. Awesome stuff

Comment: It's all Petka, he wrote it, I help :)

Answer (score 1):

Q.js appears not to offer `Q.all(object)`, therefore you will need to map your object to an array before passing to `Q.all()`

Something like this will be reusable and convenient :

```
Q.allObj = function (obj) {
    var array = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key, i) {
        try {
            //expect a promise
            return obj[key].then(function(value) {
                return {key: key, value: value};
            });
        } 
        catch(e) { 
            // whoops it was a value
            return {key: key, value: obj[key]};
        }
    });
    return Q.all(array);
};
```

Use as follows :

```
Q.allObj(myObj).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function(obj) {
        var name = obj.key;
        var value = obj.value;
        ...
    });
});
```